# Changing variable inside a class

Tags: scala

```
class B(i:Int) {
  var v = new M(i)
  class M(i: Int) {
    val x = i
    println("Creating a new M")
    println(s"x = $x")
  }
}


val b = new B(1)
val c = new B(2)
b.v = c.v
```

How do I change the variable v inside b with c.v and why can't I do this way?

Comment: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can't do such assignment is because `M` class is *not static*. Unlike java each outer class instance has it's own inner class so `b.v` and `c.v` are instance of *different types* hence you can't simple do assignment.

What you can do is to

1. Declare `M` static in scala way using companion-object

```scala
object B {
  class M(i: Int) {
    val x = i
    println("Creating a new M")
    println(s"x = $x")
  }
}

class B(i:Int) {
  import B._
  var v = new B.M(i)
}
```

2. Assign using *same instance* of class `B`

```scala
b.v = new b.M(2)
```

You can find more info on inner classes at [scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/inner-classes.html)

Comment: I'd say the first sentence of what you have up there is not correct. The reference is hidden within the closure.

Comment: @wheaties well... technically speaking non-static inner class contains a reference to outer class. that direct reflection of how java works. I'll update my answer

Comment: That's very true in Java. This question is about Scala (where it's also true.) That said, it's not the reason they can't be assigned.

Comment: @wheaties yeah. Now I get it. Actually the same code will work fine in java because in java instances of `M` class have same type which is not true for scala. Thank you for eliminating my misunderstanding! I'll remove my answer.